# Sending arrayValue in structed query of firebase in which fieldpath is also an array. How can I sent it?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is a function in which I write the  structured query to get data from firestore database. But I am not that familiar with  structured query so I don't know which value type should be sent to which fieldPath in fieldFilter.

From the below code, I want to get data from collectionId "chat-message," from which I sent arrayValue in fieldFilter, which must be equal to fieldPath "userIds," which also an array consists of two indexes.

But I keep getting error like "invalid value at structured_query.where.....

So how can I solve it and get data.

```
public static function chat_message($userId){
 $filter_maker = [["fieldFilter" => ["field" => ["fieldPath" => "userIds"], "op" => "EQUAL", "value" => ["arrayValue" => ["values" => $userId]]]],];

 $make_array_to_send = (object)["structuredQuery" => []];
 $make_array_to_send->structuredQuery = (object)["from" => [["collectionId" => "chat-messages"]], "where" => [],];
 $make_array_to_send->structuredQuery->where = (object)["compositeFilter" => []];
 $make_array_to_send->structuredQuery->where->compositeFilter = (object)["filters" => [], "op" => "AND",];
 $make_array_to_send->structuredQuery->where->compositeFilter->filters = $filter_maker;

 $make_array_to_send = (array)$make_array_to_send;

 $response = Http::post('https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/nepali-lai- kaam/databases/(default)/documents:runQuery',$make_array_to_send);

 return json_decode($response);
}
```